# Categoricity of categorical arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, incompleteness, peano-axioms, categorical-logic

Consider the elementary theory of the category of sets (ETCS). Inside this framework, we have that $(\mathbb N, 0, s)$ is a natural number objet and that :

- it is a model of the Peano axioms,
- it is unique up to isomorphism.

In other words, it seems to me that the ETCS provides a categorical characterization of the standard natural numbers (in the sense that is shows that the Peano axioms have an essentially unique model). But the ETCS is a first-order theory and seems to "contain" the usual Peano axioms, so does the uniqueness of the natural number object contradict the Gödel's incompleteness theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though ETCS proves that $\mathbb N$ is unique, that only means that *each model of ETCS* has a unique object in it that it thinks is a model of the Peano axioms. Different models of ETCS may have different $\mathbb N$s that are not isomorphic when we compare them at the metalevel (which is, of course, the only way we *can* compare them).

This is not different from the situation in ZF(C) wherein we can prove that the (second-order) Peano axioms have a unique model up to isomorphism.